# addToBackStack causing out of memery issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-support-library, heap-memory

I am adding new fragment to container either by add or replace observed it is causing heap issue.

```
  RetailSlidingTabFragment retailSlidingTabFragment = RetailSlidingTabFragment.newInstance(typeId, searchTerm, retailCategoryItem.getMenuSlug(), location, retailCategoryItem.getName());

  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,
                            android.R.anim.slide_out_right, android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right)
                    .add(R.id.main_content, retailSlidingTabFragment, "Category")
                    .addToBackStack("Category")
                    .commit();
```

**Replace fragment code**

```
 RetailSlidingTabFragment retailSlidingTabFragment = RetailSlidingTabFragment.newInstance(typeId, searchTerm, retailCategoryItem.getMenuSlug(), location, retailCategoryItem.getName());

  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,
                            android.R.anim.slide_out_right, android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right)
                    .replace(R.id.main_content, retailSlidingTabFragment, "Category")
                    .addToBackStack("Category")
                    .commit();
```

After pressing back and opening fragments couple of time this issue is occuring.
How to fix it?

Comment: it's not while adding/replacing the Fragment, there might be issue in fragment which consumes lot of memory, paste your fragment code

Comment: There is just TextView in my fragment nothing heavy

Comment: Then it should be in Activity class

Comment: No I can see heap memory increasing only when I open and close fragment again and again

Comment: are you passing any complex object like bitmap or images to Fragment ?